# Adding discrete probability distributions but treating each value as a separate bucket

Tags: statistics, probability

I imagine this problem as having `n` buckets in which we are placing books where each bucket has their own probability. I define a trial here as a book being assigned to a bucket randomly (according to their probability weights ofc). The question I'm then trying to answer is how can I determine the expected value of the number of trials required to get at least 1 book in bucket 1, 1 in bucket 2, 2 in bucket 3 and 2 in bucket 3, for example.

Initially, I thought this can be answered using a geometric random variable of some kind, or by adding random variables perhaps using the Central Limit Theorem, but I could not figure out how.

Researching online, I found some references to the Coupon Collector's problem being similar to this, as well as convolutions and even fourier transforms but none of them really answered my question. I'd appreciate any guidance on how to approach this.

Comment: A bit unclear - is it integer partition or Stars and bars (aka integer combinatorics) problem?